# Creating & Previewing MarkDown Document with PyCharm and LightTable

Tags: markdown, pycharm, lighttable

I am new to programming. Like, really new.

But the process of learning `python` programming introduced me to a lot of exciting apps for my laptop.

I am now a regular user of `PyCharm`. I recently installed `LightTable` too and liked it instantly.

Can somebody explain me or share a resource for the way to use these two applications to write and preview content using `markdown` language?

I own a blog on a 3rd party web space ([Svbtle](http://svbtle.com/)) which uses only `markdown`, and I have been using it so far comfortably. Its editing mode  allows me write and preview content. But this can be done only if I am online. I tried to understand this from their website documentation, but it was too technical for me.

I know there are many cool online tools for this. But I would like have this stuff locally installed so I can be at ease when I am offline. I also checked several other editors and IDEs, but I would like to stick on to `PyCharm` and `LightTable`. I would like to give a try at `Atom` soon. But this is it for now.

Thanks.

Comment: I just installed `[Atom](http://atom.io)` _editor_ and `markdown` is pretty straight forward. Open a file, save it as `.markdown` file and go to menu bar, find **Packages** > **Markdown** > **Toggle Preview** or the keyboard shortcut is `Shift+Ctrl+M`. That's it! You have the preview by the side. I would like to know the same in LightTable too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lighttable has a good solution for this!

### Short Answer

Install and use the `Markdown` plugin.

### Long Answer

#### Installation

1. Open the command finder: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
2. Type the command `Plugins: Show plugin manager` to open up the plugin manager.
3. Install the `Markdown` plugin and restart Lighttable.

#### Usage

5. While editing a markdown file, open the command finder: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
6. Type the command `Markdown: Watch this editor for changes`

You can then move the live-rendered markdown tab into its own tabset so that you can view it side-by-side with your editing tab while you edit!

Comment: Thanks David. That was so straight forward. Your long answer did really help me. Coz I have no idea about these all new commands to be used in Light Table? Do these commands belong to some other programming language? I would love now to know more about these Light Table specific commands, than just one usage like markdown. Hope you will find time to share more. Thanks a lot again.

Comment: The commands are specific to Lighttable, they are not part of their own programming language. The command finder (`<Ctrl>`+`<Space>`) is a great way to discover Lighttable features, and it is "fuzzy", so you can just start typing what you are curious about and see what Lighttable suggests. If you haven't seen it already, [the full Lighttable tutorial](http://docs.lighttable.com/tutorials/full/) is valuable.